# ffmpeg video cropping Invalid too big

Tags: ffmpeg, java, android

Its same issue with this but in video [ffmpeg cropping: 'Invalid too big or non positive size for width'](https://superuser.com/questions/1474942/ffmpeg-cropping-invalid-too-big-or-non-positive-size-for-width)

trying to crop the video to an aspect ratio of 9:16, the video size retrieve is Width 3840 Height 2160
and got the Invalid too big or nonpositive size for width '3836' or height '2160'

Command:

```
I/System.out: "-y" "-ss" "0" "-t" "31" "-i" "/storage/emulated/0/Download/20210227_175547.mp4" "-strict" "experimental" "-vf" "crop=w=3837:h=2160:x=1:y=-2070" "-r" "15" "-ab" "128k" "-vcodec" "mpeg4" "-acodec" "copy" "-b:v" "2500k" "-sample_fmt" "s16" "-ss" "0" "-t" "31" "/storage/emulated/0/VEditor/VideoCroper/20210227_175547-0-13.mp4"
```

Code in Java:

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.append("crop=w=");
            sb.append(this.final_width);
            sb.append(":h=");
            sb.append(this.final_height);
            sb.append(":x=");
            sb.append(this.horizontal);
            sb.append(":y=");
            sb.append(this.vertical);
            a(new String[]{"-y", "-ss", Start, "-t", Duration, "-i",file_name, "-strict", "experimental", "-vf",sb.toString(), "-r", "15", "-ab", "128k", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-acodec", "copy", "-b:v", "2500k", "-sample_fmt", "s16", "-ss", "0", "-t", this.Duration, Output}, Output);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg is auto rotating the video due to the rotate side data, so it becomes 2160x3840 before being cropped resulting in the error. You can tell it not to auto rotate with the `-noautorotate` input option.

```
I/System.out: "-y" "-noautorotate" "-ss" "0" "-t" "31" "-i" "/storage/emulated/0/Download/20210227_175547.mp4" "-vf" "crop=w=3837:h=2160:x=1:y=-2070" "-r" "15" "-vcodec" "mpeg4" "-acodec" "copy" "-b:v" "2500k" "/storage/emulated/0/VEditor/VideoCroper/20210227_175547-0-13.mp4"
```

I removed the options that don't do anything.

Comment: Awsome Brother !